# Is there any function operates as JButton pressed?

Tags: java, awt, jbutton, jtextarea, keylistener

I'm making KeyListener for JTextArea in chatting program

If I press ENTER key, JTextArea gets new line

However, I want to make ENTER key operates as "SEND" function

This is my code

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                sendButton.???
            else if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ALT + KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                inputTextArea.setText(inputTextArea.getText() + "\n");
        }
```

What should I do at the point -> ???

And is there any useful advice, teach me and let my program develop :)

Comment: [`doClick()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `KeyListener` with text components, it's just generally bad practice, instead, you want to take control of the `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` key binding action and insert your custom functionality there...

Now, the trick is, letting the existing `Action` still work, cause you don't want any more work then you need...

This can be achieved by getting the `Action` associated with the `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER`...

```
InputMap im = ta.getInputMap(JTextArea.WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap am = ta.getActionMap();

Object key = im.get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
Action insertBreak = am.get(key);
```

Then, you would set your own action to be triggered in it's place, passing the previous action to it, so it can called when you want it to be...

```
am.put(key, new MyNewOnEnterAction(insertBreak));

//...

public class MyNewOnEnterAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Action proxy;

    public MyNewOnEnterAction(Action proxy) {
        this.proxy = proxy;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Your custom functionality here...
        proxy.actionPerformed(e);
    }

}
```

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private JLabel status;

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 10);
                InputMap im = ta.getInputMap(JTextArea.WHEN_FOCUSED);
                ActionMap am = ta.getActionMap();

                Object key = im.get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
                Action insertBreak = am.get(key);

                am.put(key, new MyNewOnEnterAction(insertBreak));

                status = new JLabel("...");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {

    }

    public class MyNewOnEnterAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Action proxy;

        public MyNewOnEnterAction(Action proxy) {
            this.proxy = proxy;
        }

        public int getLineAtCaret(JTextComponent component) {
            int caretPosition = component.getCaretPosition();
            Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();

            return root.getElementIndex(caretPosition) + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JTextArea ta = (JTextArea) e.getSource();
            int line = getLineAtCaret(ta);
            try {
                int startPos = ta.getLineStartOffset(line - 1);
                int endPos = ta.getLineEndOffset(line - 1);
                Document doc = ta.getDocument();

                String text = doc.getText(startPos, endPos - startPos);
                status.setText(text);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            proxy.actionPerformed(e);
        }

    }

}
```

This will get the current line of text and set it to the `status` `JLabel`'s `text`...

Personally, I would setup either a class or method that both your key binding `Action` and your button can call...or you could even use the same `Action`, who knows ;)

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details